# Use different screen resolution in vncviewer session from the server

Tags: screen, vino, vncviewer

I have a 1920x1080 screen connected directly to my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server.

I am connecting to it via `vino` (server side) and `vncviewer` (client side, Win 10).
In my client, I have a 1366x768 screen.

**Is there any way to adapt the screen resolution for the remote session (i.e., without changing the resolution in the server), so I don't have to scroll in the vncviewer session to access the whole screen?**

PS: In the vncviewer connection options there is a tab *Screen*.
There are two check boxes
*Resize remote session on connect* (with a resolution of 1366 x 768 specified)
and
*Resize remote session to the local window*
They appear to provide for the intended effect, but they do not.

PS2: There is some info on how to do this with `vncserver`, e.g. below.
But I have found none for `vino`.

https://superuser.com/questions/184338/how-to-change-screen-resolution-of-vnc-server-without-restarting-it

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try

```
     vncserver -geometry 1366x768
```

instead of sticking with the vino configuration?  It's not the same as altering the system screen resolution, only the resolution put out by vnc.

Comment: As I understand, `vncserver` is a command for other VNC servers, not `vino`.
I actually don't have `vncserver`.

Comment: Since vino does not publish an option for adjusting screen resolution, but vncserver does, I think replacing vncserver on the 18.04 LTS system is the most practical solution.

Comment: Ok. Would you say that allows for having 1920x1080 in the console and 1366x768 in the remote system? That is the question in the OP.

Comment: You would retain the 1920 x 1080 resolution on the Ubuntu server, but I expect the command would publish a 1366 x 768  scaled view for the vncviewer client in Windows to use more conveniently.